# can I do test shibboleth IdP and SP on localhost environment?

Tags: localhost, saml, shibboleth

can I do test shibboleth IdP and SP on localhost environment?

I have just one PC(Win7)

Answer (score 6):

**Yes** you sure can.

Download and install SP and idP in that machine, configure metadata for both to communicate to localhost or for better ease use two domains for SP and idP,

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` here add two domains `localhost-sp` and `localhost-idp` to the `hosts` file.

So you have now two differet domains for sp and idp.