# Is it possible to connect Shibboleth idp from localhost?

Tags: shibboleth

I installed Shibboleth service provider on localhost. I want to connect to shibboleth idp.

> Error Message: No peer endpoint available to which to send SAML response

This is because I connect to IDP(idp.shibtest.org) from localhost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[samltest.id](https://samltest.id/) is good way to test shibboleth.

You ***cannot use localhost as SP to connect to remote IDp***, that iDp won't find any SP to return to because **localhost means it's own system** so IDp would go in it's local system and find your given SP's entity ID. It won't find that entity ID so it would give such error.

*These two approach may help you*

1. Give your machine some **public IP** and try connect to IDp with that SP.
2. If you cannot make public IP, **make both SP and IDp in your local system**.
   My [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278524/1534925) answer may help you.