# Possible to do Shibboleth authentication on local dev environment?

Tags: saml, shibboleth

I have a Java/Spring application that is running on a Tomcat server. The application uses Shibboleth/SAML for getting user access and it works fine.

However I would like to run/debug the application on my local dev environment(on local Tomcat). I wonder if it is possible to set up something and get prompted by the same service provider so that I can log into the application like it is on the production environment.

Comment: What is stopping you to start Identity Provider locally with SAML support (e.g. Keycloak) and use it with your Service Provider?

Comment: @JanGaraj Should I do that, and how do I do that? I don't mind doing any changes on my localhost (and other developer's local environments). I just don't want to change anything within the Java source

Comment: Start your favorite/selected IDP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML-based_products_and_services) and follow their doc how to install/configure/use it.

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/28061252/1534925

> [samltest.id][1] is good way to test shibboleth.
>
> You ***cannot use localhost as SP to connect to remote IDp***, that
> iDp won't find any SP to return to because **localhost means it's own
> system** so IDp would go in it's local system and find your given SP's
> entity ID. It won't find that entity ID so it would give such error.
>
> *These two approach may help you*
>
> 1. Give your machine some **public IP** and try connect to IDp with that SP.
> 2. If you cannot make public IP, **make both SP and IDp in your local system**. My [**this**][2] answer may help you.
>
> [1]: https://samltest.id/   [2]:
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278524/1534925

and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278524/1534925

> **Yes** you sure can.
>
> Download and install SP and idP in that machine, configure metadata
> for both to communicate to localhost or for better ease use two
> domains for SP and idP,
>
> `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` here add two domains `localhost-sp`
> and `localhost-idp` to the `hosts` file.
>
> So you have now two differet domains for sp and idp.